# How to get log just for last 5 minutes from command line

Tags: android, time, android-logcat, android-log

How to get log for recent time, for example, for last 5 minutes?

This command in command line

```
adb logcat -v time | find "E/"
```

gives error logs for all time.

(It's not interesting to wait several minutes while all logs is displaying)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`adb logcat -T "$(date +'%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q' -d '5 minutes ago')"`

### Caveats:

- Uses time from host system, not device so if there is drift you have to correct for it
- Requires a POSIX shell and `date` command (works on Linux and Mac, not sure windows)

Comment: I get `WARNING: -T  invalid, setting to 1`

Answer (score 0):

The `-v time` command displays the date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the process issuing the message. So it is not a filter for the actual timestamp of the log. I do not believe there is a way to do this.

Though, you can clear the log with `adb logcat -c`.

Comment: after applying "adb logcat -c" anyway i receive log for all time(

Comment: Well, that's strange. What version of Android are you using? Just looking it up now, it looks like this is a known issue for Lollipop: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78916

Comment: Yes, it seems because of version issue. Mine is 6.0.1

Comment: And, upon further inspection, I found this as the known workaround: `NOW=$(date +"%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000") ; adb logcat -T "$NOW"`, which may actually be what you were looking for originally.

Comment: Also strange, I am on 6.0.1 as well, but it works for me.

Comment: By don't say that you also have Nexus 7=))

Comment: Bryan, do you know if it's possible to apply any symbols like '?' or '*' to filter. For example i can filter logs by content like
adb logcat -v time | find "20:04" so it shows all logs for time 20:04

Comment: Haha, I do actually, but I was using my Nexus 5X to test just now.

Comment: Hm, you could possibly use a `grep` command, let me look into that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102022/discussion-between-kiryl-ivanou-and-bryan).